# Really Slow Boot Time Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, services

I have been having issues with my laptop that I recently installed Ubuntu on.

The boot time is significantly slow, and I used `systemd-analyze blame` to see which services are causing the issues. I will list them below, and if anybody has any suggestions on how to alleviate this issue, I'd appreciate it.

```
1.674s plymouth-start.service
1.615s dev-mmcblk0p1.device
1.276s networking.service
1.114s apparmor.service
572ms snapd.firstboot.service
550ms ModemManager.service
540ms accounts-daemon.service
472ms grub-common.service
468ms console-setup.service
464ms NetworkManager.service
439ms systemd-rfkill.service
391ms systemd-logind.service
382ms thermald.service
374ms irqbalance.service
338ms systemd-udevd.service
297ms ondemand.service
292ms avahi-daemon.service
291ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
266ms apport.service
263ms bluetooth.service
251ms speech-dispatcher.service
233ms keyboard-setup.service
233ms pppd-dns.service
```

Comment: I guess it really comes down to what you're willing to sacrifice. I'm guessing by dev-mmcblk0p1 that you have an SD card reader, do you need it? Does it have a card inserted? (take it out!). Do you have 3g/4g wireless (seemingly indicated by modemmanager). Do you need bluetooth functionality? etc etc. Basically turn off some stuff if you don't need it. Also if your hardward is old you can always upgrade.